# I forgot to put down the number of the loan

Tags: loans, deposits

I deposited money as a loan payment to the company that has given me the loan under my name. The amount is correct, the account number is correct, and it's under my name. I have only forgotten the loan number. Will anything bad happen? I'm scared of losing my money...

Answer (score 3):

Generally if there are enough details, they would match this up with your loan account and pass appropriate credit.

The worst that can happen is;

- Payment gets returned as they cannot apply to your loan account.
- Payment is kept under hold and not applied to your loan account.

In either case, watch your Loan account statement and it should show you the credit. If this does not then ask the company and they should be able to trace it and rectify.

Under no scenario you would lose money.

Comment: also check your checking account website to see if it was cashed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about it, call up the loan company and confirm that they received the payment and that they credited it properly. If they received the payment but did not credit it properly to your loan, the customer service representative on the phone should be able to make the adjustment, as well as remove any late fee that might have been applied as a result of the misapplied payment.